Quick question about the notation: $(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ in inverse limit of the inverse system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from: A Graduate Course In Algebra - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then , the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 3:  An inverse system of groups (respectively topological groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc) is  a family $G_i, i\in I$, of groups, together with a family of homomorphisms $f_{ij}:G_i\to G_j,i\succeq j$ such that :

$f_{ii}=1_{G_i}.$

Whenever $i\succeq j \succeq k,$ then $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}.$


Definition 4:  The inverse (or projective limit of the inverse system of groups $G_i,$ is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism $$\phi_i:G\to G_i$$
for each $i\in I$ satisfying

If $i \succeq j$ then $\phi_j= f_{ij}\circ \phi_i$, i.e. the homomorphism $\phi_i$ are compatible with the inverse system.

Given another group $H$ and $\psi_i:G_i\to H$ compatible with the inverse system, then there is a unique homomorphism $\psi:H\to G$ such that $\psi_i=\phi_i\circ \psi$ for any $i \in I$.
We write


$$G=\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i$$.
In the categories of sets, groups, rings etc., inverse limits always exist and admit the following description:
$$\varprojlim_{i\in I}G_i= \left\{(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i\mid f_{ji}(g_j)=g_i \text{ for all }i\preceq j \right\}$$.
Questions:
In continuation from the following post, and post. I have quick question about the notation $(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ for $2.$ Definition 4 above.  Specifically, the $g_i$s in $(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i$, there could be infinitely many $g_i$s, like $(g_1g_2....)\in  \prod_{i\in I}G_i$?  The reason I am asking is because there doesn't seem to be restriction place on elements for direct product of groups.  But direct sum, restrictions are usually place upon the elements.  Also, the addition of the condition $i\preceq j$ is affecting how I am understanding $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$.
Thank you in advance

I'm  not sure I understand your question, but there are indeed no restrictions on the $g_i$'s in the $(g_1, g_2,....) \in \Pi_{i\in I} G_i$ except for the restriction that $g_i \in G_i$.  The set $I$ could be finite, infinite (countably or uncoutably infnite), as long as it is partially ordered. So depending on $I$, there could be infinitely many. For direct sums there are indeed restrictions, but the direct product is different and the restrictions of the direct sum arent used for direct products.

@JosefK. what I want to know is the way the notation is defined for the set of $g_i$s, could $(g_i)\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ denote an infinite-tuple?

If $I$ is infinite in cardinality, $(g_i)_{i\in I}$ is an 'infinite tuple'. Lets say that $I = \mathbb{N}$, then this would mean that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is an element $g_n \in G_n$ on the $n$-th location of the tuple.

@JosefK so if $n=5$, then we have something like $(1_{G_1},1_{G_2},1_{G_3},1_{G_4},g_5,1_{G_6},1_{G_7},\ldots)$?

That would be one element of the set, but it is important to note that the groups $G_i$ can be all different, so I'd denote it like $(1_{G_1}, 1_{G_2},...,g_5 \in G_5, 1_{G_6},....)$. But note that it is true for EVERY $n$ that, incase $I = \mathbb{N}$, we would have an element $g_n$ on the $n-$th position. In this case $n=1 $ has $g_1 = 1_G{g_1}$ on the first position, etc.

@JosefK I am still a bit unclear.  The way $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ is defined.  Do I predefined which $i$-s in say $I=\mathbb{N}$ where $f(i)=g_i\neq 1_{G_i}$?  This way, there could be finite or infinite number of $i$-s so that $g_i\neq 1_{G_i}$

@JosefK I should add that, the addition of the condition $i\preceq j$ is affecting how I am understanding $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$.

If you want to understand the specifics of inverse limits I'd recommend reading more about them in a formal book. To give you some intuition, you determine properties of 'lower' elements in the chain $(g_{i\in I})$ by elements higher up in the chain. You are given the family of $f_{i,j}$ and using these and the rules of the inverse system, you go 'from top to bottom' in determining the elements $g_i$. This may seem a bit vague, but to get a feeling, you might want to look what happens if you set $I = \mathbb{N}$, and pick, for $i=1,2,3$ some groups and elements and look what happens.

@JosepfK can you recommend me a book with some concrete examples.  The thing is when I have the condition $i\preceq j$, so let's say that $I=\mathbb{N}$, and $j=5$ and the partial order $\preceq$ is the standard inequality $<$.  Then for $i=1$, $g_1$, for $i=2$, $(g_1,g_2)$, $i=3$ $(g_1,g_2,g_3)$ and $i=4$, we have $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$?  Is this correct?

I know that Lang's 'Algebra' contains some examples (but i'm not sure if these are particularly enlightening, I don't know if there are any books with particularly great examples already written out). Mabye looking at Dummit and Foote chapter 7.6 exercise 11 could help.

@JosefK. I wrote out the example for the case $j=5$ with partial order $<$ in the previous comment to yours just now.  Is the way I am understanding it correct?  I am trying to understand how you explain it to me with a concrete example.

What I tried to say is, use some particular groups, and pick explicit elements in this group to play around with the definition (if you pick some elements in the group, see what happens) The exercise I mentioned might help you with that.

Yes, you're entirely correct, that the product (both in a definitional sense and in a category-theory sense) consists of collections $(g_i)$ with $g_i\in G_i$ and no further conditions. (And, then, various projective limits involving the $G_i$'s do add conditions, but not generally "finiteness" conditions.)
Yes, in contrast, the "forward/inductive/coproduct/direct-sum of the $G_i$, BUT ONLY FOR ABELIAN GROUPS, is, as a construction/definition depending how we approach things, the subgroup of the product consisting of tuples in which all but finitely-many are the identity in $G_i$. As a random definition, this is not satisfying, but does turn out to give a reasonable construction (hence, proof-of-existence-by-construction) of "categorical" coproducts of abelian groups.
For non-abelian $G_i$, "coproducts" are sometimes called "amalgamated products", etc., which include free groups, and are much more complicated things...

is my last comment to JosefK correct in how I am understanding the inverse limit.  Also, I have your algebra text at home.  Sometimes I look at it, and wish more books are written the way you and Pierre Grillet write their math books.

@Seth, I'm glad you find my writing helpful. I'll look at this situation more tomorrow... :)
